# Libertine font displays slightly bold in XeLaTex compared to PdfLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, pdftex, memoir, libertine

I love using `libertine` font in my document. It looks nice and clear when compiled using `pdflatex`. But I got different result when compiled using `xelatex`. It seems to be a slightly bold in my screen. Is there any chances to get it nice and clear result in `xelatex`? thanks. // ps: I'm using `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2014)`, texmaker 4.1 under ubuntu linux 14.04 lts.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
This is normal text, \emph{emphasized text}, and \textbf{bold text}.

\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image: left: pdflatex. right: xelatex]

Update #1: here's screenshot from the properties menu of the PDF viewer (Evince). Both `pdflatex` and `xelatex` use `\usepackage{libertine}`.

[image: font comparison]

Update #2: ...and this is when using `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}` with `xelatex` (as @jason-zentz's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228839/libertine-font-displays-slightly-bold-in-xelatex-compared-to-pdflatex#comment540129_228839)).

[image: using xelatex fontspec]

Comment: Did you try printing it, or using a different viewer?

Comment: Did you confirm that the same font is embedded in both PDFs (e.g., Linux Libertine O and not Linux Libertine T)? (You can use `pdffonts` or the properties menu of the PDF viewer for this.)

Comment: Do you see the same difference if you use `\usepackage{libertine}` with pdfLaTeX but `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}` with XeLaTeX? You would need to have the `.otf` files installed in your system fonts directory for the `fontspec` approach to work, but it gives you a lot more flexibility (e.g., you can specify that the true bold rather than the default semibold should be used for bold text).

Comment: They look exactly the same when I compile your document (and yes, I do get ``LinLibertineT`` with pdflatex and ``LinLibertineO`` with xelatex, as expected). I only get some minor differences with kerning and hyphenations. My guess is that they only seem different because of your pdf viewer. As Juri says, print them and then compare.

Comment: @AndrewCashner: they use different name. please see my update above.

Comment: @JasonZentz: you're right. it looks much better when using `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}` in `xelatex`. It show different fonts name in the properties menu (see update #2 above). I think this one works well for me for now. Thanks, mate :)

Comment: @JuriRobl: I just saw it on screen (using default pdf viewer, Evince), then printed just now. Both look the same when printed. Thanks.

Comment: @Sverre: Yes, they both look the same. I printed it just now :) I think I like this one, as the bold text doesn't change. Using `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}` makes bold text looks slightly thinner in my opinion. Thanks :)

Comment: @guest_5758, To get the true bold instead of semibold, use `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}[BoldFont={Linux Libertine O Bold}]`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126029/42880.

Comment: @JasonZentz: Now it works perfect. Thanks a lot, mate :)

Comment: @JasonZentz Sounds like an answer :) (or, perhaps, a duplicate)

Comment: @SeanAllred, I wouldn't say this is a duplicate of the semibold/bold question because the OP was seeing a difference in weight between the TrueType and OpenType versions of the normal roman, only in the PDF viewer and not on paper. @Sverre and I weren't able to replicate that problem, so it must be specific to the viewer. I just suggested the `fontspec` solution, and the bold/semibold issue is a side effect of that. I'm not sure why `fontspec` fixes the original viewer issue, since it calls the same OpenType font that `libertine` in XeLaTeX does.

Comment: This is possibly the actual explanation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305258/xelatex-font-rendering-tend-to-be-slightly-bolder-compared-to-pdflatex